# Why are float and double lambda parameters restricted to the float value set, double value set?

Tags: java, lambda, jls

Reading the Java Language Specification, Java SE 8 Edition, I saw something interesting in §15.27.1 Lambda Parameters:

> A lambda parameter of type `float` always contains an element of the float value set (§4.2.3); similarly, a lambda parameter of type `double` always contains an element of the double value set. It is not permitted for a lambda parameter of type `float` to contain an element of the float-extended-exponent value set that is not also an element of the float value set, nor for a lambda parameter of type `double` to contain an element of the double-extended-exponent value set that is not also an element of the double value set.

This seems to imply that the VM will first map an extended precision `float` or `double` value to the (non-extended) float or double value set via value set conversion before the lambda expression or lambda body is evaluated. However, the spec stops short of requiring evaluation of the lambda to be FP-strict, and it appears not to be possible to make a "`strictfp` lambda expression/body".

I suppose this means that the following two statements are not strictly equivalent:

```
doubleStream.map((operand) -> operand + 2.);

doubleStream.map(new DoubleUnaryOperator() {
    @Override
    public double applyAsDouble(double operand) {
        return operand + 2.;
    }
});
```

Is this correct?

What is the reason why the JLS requires the values of `float` and `double` lambda parameters to be within the float value set or double value set, respectively?

Comment: The same language appears in the Java Language Specification, Java SE 8 Edition.

Comment: @JonathanRosenne Yes, you're right. I didn't mean to imply that this was new language in JLS 9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the final draft of [JSR-335](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=335), Part B of the Lambda Specification mentions immediately following the "A lambda parameter of type `float`" paragraph:

> The previous seven paragraphs are derived from 8.4.1 "Formal Parameters."

It turns out that §8.4.1 Formal Parameters includes a similarly-worded paragraph pertaining to the parameters of methods and constructors:

> A method or constructor parameter of type `float` always contains an element of the float value set (§4.2.3); similarly, a method or constructor parameter of type `double` always contains an element of the double value set. It is not permitted for a method or constructor parameter of type `float` to contain an element of the float-extended-exponent value set that is not also an element of the float value set, nor for a method parameter of type `double` to contain an element of the double-extended-exponent value set that is not also an element of the double value set.

I checked all the way back to JLS 2 and saw that this paragraph has been there all along.

So, the two statements in the question are, in fact, equivalent to one another.